# What does “don't get cheap on me” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

It is perhaps one of the most famous quotes in the Jurassic Park movie:

> *Dennis Nedry:* Don't get cheap on me, Dodgson. That was Hammond's mistake.
> <sub>Source: [IMDb > Dennis Nedry (Character) > Quotes](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0002044/quotes)</sub>
> <sub>[[video of the scene]](http://youtu.be/D4MUBQNbTYo?t=1m44s)</sub>

Can anyone please tell me what it means exactly?

Comment: Related:  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24321/parse-go-all-shaky-on-me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall the context in the movie, but in general:

cheap: inexpensive or of poor quality.

> I got an extra dozen eggs this week because they were cheap.
>
> I didn't buy the bookcase because it looked flimsy and cheap.

slang: "cheap shot" is a verbal or physical attack that is very easy and considered cheating)

> The comment about Andy's hair was a cheap shot, he already feels bad about it.

"Cheap" can refer to either the cost of a thing, or to describe a person that only likes cheap things.

> My Dad is too cheap to buy new paint.

"Don't **_**  on me": Don't do this around me or to me or in a way that affects me.

> Don't eat all the ice cream on me.

So the phrase "Don't get cheap on me." could mean one of:

- You need to spend more money/time on something for me.
- You need to think about money less.
- You should not tease/attack me like that.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the first option at the end of your comment would be the answer for this phrase based on the story's context

Comment: The context is that a waiter has just placed a bill between the two characters. I've edited a link to the video into the question if you're interested.

Comment: Yes, in that case the speaker thinks the other person should pay the bill.